# Python OpenCV VideoWriter.write() unexplained time inconsistency

Tags: python, opencv, encoding, video-encoding

I am unable to figure out the exact reason behind why the opencv videowriter.write() takes more time when ran sequentially without any a relatively costly blocking operation in between, compared to when there is a blocking call.

Take a look at the following two code blocks, the only difference b/w the two is that one has a small wait/delay b/w consecutive frame write operation.

**Code 1 with no inter frame delay**

```
import cv2
import time

videoReader = cv2.VideoCapture("1080_1920.mp4")
videoWriter = cv2.VideoWriter('processed.mp4', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'H264'), 25.0, (1920,1080))

totalWaitTime = 0
totalEncodingTime = 0
totalTimeOverall = 0

tBegin = time.time()

while(True):

    ret, frame = videoReader.read()
    if not ret:
        break

    t3 = time.time()
    # time.sleep(0.01)
    t4 = time.time()
    totalWaitTime += (t4-t3)

    t5 = time.time()
    videoWriter.write(frame)
    t6 = time.time()
    totalEncodingTime += (t6-t5)


    print(f"tSlp: {t4-t3:.4f}, tEnc: {t6-t5:.4f}")
    print("-"*30)

tEnd = time.time()

totalTimeOverall = tEnd-tBegin

print("="*50,'\n Summary : ')
print(f"Time taken   : {totalTimeOverall:.4f} \t --%")
print(f"Of which slp : {totalWaitTime:.4f} \t {int(totalWaitTime*100/totalTimeOverall)}%")
print(f"Of which enc : {totalEncodingTime:.4f} \t {int(totalEncodingTime*100/totalTimeOverall)}%")
```

**Output Code 1**
Note : the total encoding time is about 5.5 seconds.
[image: Output Code 1]

**Code 2 with small inter frame delay**

```
import cv2
import time

videoReader = cv2.VideoCapture("1080_1920.mp4")
videoWriter = cv2.VideoWriter('processed.mp4', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'H264'), 25.0, (1920,1080))

totalWaitTime = 0
totalEncodingTime = 0
totalTimeOverall = 0

tBegin = time.time()

while(True):

    ret, frame = videoReader.read()
    if not ret:
        break

    t3 = time.time()
    time.sleep(0.01)
    t4 = time.time()
    totalWaitTime += (t4-t3)

    t5 = time.time()
    videoWriter.write(frame)
    t6 = time.time()
    totalEncodingTime += (t6-t5)


    print(f"tSlp: {t4-t3:.4f}, tEnc: {t6-t5:.4f}")
    print("-"*30)

tEnd = time.time()

totalTimeOverall = tEnd-tBegin

print("="*50,'\n Summary : ')
print(f"Time taken   : {totalTimeOverall:.4f} \t --%")
print(f"Of which slp : {totalWaitTime:.4f} \t {int(totalWaitTime*100/totalTimeOverall)}%")
print(f"Of which enc : {totalEncodingTime:.4f} \t {int(totalEncodingTime*100/totalTimeOverall)}%")
```

**Output Code 2**
Note : the total encoding time has now decreased about 3.3 seconds.
[image: Output Code 2]

**Load snapshot of code 1**
[image: Load snapshot of code 1]

**Load snapshot of code 2**
[image: Load snapshot of code 2]

**My thoughts and what I have tested so far**
Looking at the load snapshots attached below, during execution of code 1, the CPU spikes to 100%
while for code 2 it does not. This may mean that CPU is bottle-necking, but given that the operation (videowriter.write()) is synchronous not async, the total time should have ideally remained same?
What I have tried is read all frames in memory as opposed to sequentially reading them in the loop, and then write the frames sequentially, this did not change the results.
I also change the writing pipeline with gstreamer to write a UDP stream, as opposed to writing on a file on disk, to test a hypothesis that DISK I/O maybe bottle-necking. but this experiment did not change the results either.

What I am looking for is the core reason behind why the total encoding time goes down when a small delay is added in loop.

Comment: Can you try cv2.SetNumThreads(1) in the beginning of you program?

Comment: It did not change the behaviour, 5.6 seconds w/o sleep and 3.6 seconds with sleep.

Comment: The issue is not reproducible, the code with small delays is about twice longer in my machine. I see you are using a laptop, maybe the CPU is overheated. If you have Intel Gen 12 or Gen 13, it might be related to P cores versus E cores. There are many more possibilities. I suggest you to recheck the code with a desktop PC (if possible).

Comment: Tested on a desktop with i7-12700H, w/o sleep total encoding time : 0.35s, with sleep total encoding time : 0.219s.


Side note: I also tested with a different codec (mp4v) on my laptop, and the behavior did not change, the time went up to 14 and 8 seconds for w/o and with sleep respectively.